# How to change the backgrounds in isolinux

Tags: images, syslinux

I've been messing with this problem for a while now, and it seems like there isn't much documentation, or people who have asked about this before. I've been trying to change the back640x480.jpg, back800x600.jpg,and welcome.jpg file in isolinux, but when I make the iso and boot it, none of the pictures show up. its just black instead of the modified images.

I also change them in the bootlogo CPIO archive, and then recompress it.

How can I make these image show?

Comment: Are the permissions on the changed images the same as in the originals? Are the new images _exactly_ the same size as the originals? Are they the same format?

Comment: @terdon Yeah, they are all .jpg, exact same size, same permissions. I even tried with various different file sizes, and color palettes. Asside from the filename, it doesn't look like there's any other types of referrence to other properties of the images.

Comment: Have you tried opening one of the original images, making a small change and saving it with the same name? Can you see the edited image?

Comment: @terdon Ok, I tried just making a small red dot on the wallpaper, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Also, I tried doing it to only one image out of the three, and it was the only one that didn't work. It's definitely something to do with a property of the image that is lost when I open it with gimp, and then save it back.